# how to add these 3 lines as enviroment variables to .profile bash file

Tags: environment-variables

How do I add these 3 lines into `.profile` as environment variables:

```
BBSCONFIG /home/tony/majorbbs.cfg    
BBSDISP xwindow   
DISPLAY hostname:0.0
```

Answer (score 4):

```
cat >> ~/.profile <<x
export BBSCONFIG=/home/tony/majorbbs.cfg    
export BBSDISP=xwindow   
export DISPLAY=hostname:0.0
x
```

What this piece of code does is to append the three lines to the end of the `.profile` file in your home directory. (The `<<x` tells the `cat` command to copy from the terminal until it sees a lone `x`; the `>> ~/.profile` appends that text to the file`.)

The changes will be effective when you next log in.

You may find that `DISPLAY` is automatically set when you're using an appropriate display, so it would generally be better not to set that one yourself.

Comment: This is a great way to add and create files, but it could also be confusing for newcomers.

Comment: @ryanpcmcquen yes, you're right. I considered saying that the OP should use their editor and decided that it was possible they didn't know about any of the usual editors. I'll amend the Answer to describe briefly what the code is doing.

Comment: Thank you, although I prefer `EOF` or `EOT` to `x` as it looks clearer.

Comment: @ryanpcmcquen that's fine. There's nothing special about `EOF` or `EOT` though, and I wouldn't want to give the impression that they are magical in any way

Answer (score 1):

You can just edit that file with any text editor (`vim` for example).

Run `vim ~/.profile` or `nano ~/.profile`.

Note that your variables need `=` added:

```
BBSCONFIG=/home/tony/majorbbs.cfg    
BBSDISP=xwindow   
DISPLAY=hostname:0.0
```

You could also use echo:

```
echo "BBSCONFIG=/home/tony/majorbbs.cfg" >> ~/.profile
echo "BBSDISP=xwindow" >> ~/.profile
echo "DISPLAY=hostname:0.0" >> ~/.profile
```

If you need those variables available to sub-processes, you should also add these lines:

```
export BBSCONFIG
export BBSDISP
export DISPLAY
```

Note that putting `export` on the same line, as `export FOO=bar` is NOT supported in all shells.

Comment: Don't the variables need to be prefixed with *export* to get set as environmentals?

Comment: Only if they need these variables available to sub processes. Better to test without `export`, and then add later if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You add environment variables in `~/.profile` or in `~/.bash_rc` but it just works for the actual user. That is to say, it you want to have it locally so add them to the files previously mentioned, either with a text editor like vim or nano, or with the append command `>>` like previous answers already mention.
You can also add these variables, in the same format:
`export BBSCONFIG=/home/tony/majorbbs.cfg
export BBSDISP=xwindow
export DISPLAY=hostname:0.0`

but in `/etc/profile` or `/etc/environment` to make them appear globally to other users.